# d3 circles in the centre of rectangles

Tags: d3.js

Sorry to ask a trivial question. I am trying to draw some rectangles (treemap) from json file and overlay a circle on the centre of each rectangle. I am also trying to label the rectangles. The console shows correct values, But, the text is not visible & the circles are not in the centre of each rectangle. The This is a very simple task and I am new to d3. Can you please help me to correct the mistake I am doing? [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Treemap </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<script>

    var jsondata = [
        {
            "name" : "Middle East",
            "size" : 861482,
            "x" : 18,
            "y" : 18,
            "width" : 415.57094333304099,
            "height" : 484
        },
        {
            "name" : "Australasia",
            "size" : 80696,
            "x" : 433.57094333304099,
            "y" : 226.66857473176645,
            "width" : 68.429056666959013,
            "height" : 275.33142526823355
        },
        {
            "name" : "Europe",
            "size" : 61158,
            "x" : 433.57094333304099,
            "y" : 18,
            "width" : 68.429056666959013,
            "height" : 208.66857473176645
        }
        ];


    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1000)
            .attr("height", 1000);
    //var svgContainer = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");

    var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
            .data(jsondata)
            .enter()
            .append("rect");

    var rect = rectangles.attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
            .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height; })
            .style("fill", "green")
            .style("stroke", "white")
            .style("stroke-width", "0.5")
            .style("z-index", "1");

    rect.append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 2; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 2; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
            .style("font-family", "Verdana")
            .style("font-size", "18")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .style("z-index", "2");



    var dots = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
            .data(jsondata)
            .enter()
            .append("circle");

    var dot = dots.attr("cx", function (d) { return (d.x + d.width) / 2 ; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return (d.y + d.height) / 2 ; })
            .attr("r", "5")
            .style("fill", "white");
            //.style("z-index", "3");



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [replied on the D3 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/1j4j_DAI3Ac/CqrC85xL7RkJ), although Jaime is correct on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

You have to append text inside svgContainer as shown in the code below. The calculation you used for finding center of rectangle is wrong. Try this.

```
var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("g")
        .data(jsondata)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

var rect = rectangles.append("rect").attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height; })
        .style("fill", "green")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "0.5")
        .style("z-index", "1");

rectangles     
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 2; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 15; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .style("font-family", "Verdana")
        .style("font-size", "18")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .style("z-index", "2");


var dots = rectangles.append("circle").attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x+(d.width/2) ; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y+(d.height/2) ; })
        .attr("r", "5")
        .style("fill", "white");
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uxenjwh/15/)

Comment: A small suggestion: rather than binding the rect, circle and text individually, you could bind a set of "g"s once and append each to that g directly as you tried above. It cuts down binding and might also layer them more intuitively if there's any overlap.

Comment: You can simplify the code further by translating each g, which effectively shifts the origin and simpifies the amount of positioning you need to do with each rect (none), text (simple offset each time) and circle (just move to the centre). See http://jsfiddle.net/1uxenjwh/16/.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things to make it work:

1. You can't add a `text` element inside a `rect` so you need to append your `text` nodes to the `svgContainer` and for that to work, you need to do the `.selectAll('text').data(jsondata).enter().append('text')` as you are doing with the circles.
2. The center of the rectangles is the position of the rect plus half of the width/height, you are doing the position plus the width/height and all of it divided by 2, so your parents are in the wrong place.

Hope this helps.

Jaime